# Filter In Calculated Field (Pivot Table) Not Working if There Are Multiple Rows

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

My pivot table was working perfectly until this week started and a second row appeared. I am using a calculated field to avoid making more physical columns. Noticed that I had forgotten to add a second filter condition, so I went ahead and did so.

Original:

`=COUNTA(FILTER(TikTokFollowers, TikTokRemoved = "Account"))`
`=SUM(FILTER(TikTokFollowers, TikTokRemoved = "Account"))`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG2Af.png)

Updated:

`=COUNTA(FILTER(TikTokFollowers, TikTokRemoved = "Account", TikTokWeek = Week))`
`=SUM(FILTER(TikTokFollowers, TikTokRemoved = "Account", TikTokWeek = Week))`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaKCV.png)

While the error says that no matches are found, they do appear when double-clicking:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoCTn.png)

What is wrong? Really frustrating. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17sXKenpDEdY8BAMbVrwXBudG2rUM-UQdyFUePxqvEhk) is a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Just removed](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17sXKenpDEdY8BAMbVrwXBudG2rUM-UQdyFUePxqvEhk/edit#gid=450358465) the `tab_name` appended to the `headers` within the custom formula:*

```js
=COUNTA(FILTER(Followers, Removed = "Account", Week = Week))
```

[image]

Comment: Sol! I remember you. Thank you for such a quick reply. :) It works nicely on this weekly table now! The account part also works for the monthly table, but as soon as I update the followers part to =COUNTA(FILTER(F, Removed = "Account", Week = Week)), it gives the same error.

Comment: Same thing if I update this in the Total Views of the weekly YouTube table: =SUM(FILTER(Views, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(Title), "lite"), Removal = "1", Week = Week))+SUM(FILTER(Views, NOT(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(Title), "lite")), Removal = "1", Week = Week))

Comment: Changed the custom formula setting  `summarize to custom` to fix the issue